# ng2-split-pane adjusting height of a vertical pane after initial render

Tags: javascript, css, angular, npm, panel

Once the page initializes, I can't find a way to resize the height of a vertical panel. If I select the split pane component with jquery and set a min height the component does not respond by resizing its separator or internal panel. Is there any way to change the height of a vertical panel dynamically after the initial page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way, just needed to target .v-outer instead of the actual container.